# How do I save a multi dimension array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to save data from a multidimensional array in my POST data to my database but I don't know how to do it with more than 2 "array[][]"

this is what I have now.

index.php

```
$i = 0;
foreach($row as $new){
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][price]' id='price' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][name]' id='name' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][field]' id='field' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][other]' id='other' type="number" size="4">
$i++;
}

form_submit.php
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $val) {
    $price = $val['price'];
    $name= $val['name'];
    $field= $val['field'];
    $other= $val['other'];

    //query that saves into database works 
}
```

but I want to send something like this

index.php

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach($row as $new){
?>
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][price][<?php $new->id; ?>]' id='price' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][name][<?php $new->id; ?>]' id='name' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][field][<?php $new->id; ?>]' id='field' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php echo $i?>][other][<?php $new->id; ?>]' id='other' type="number" size="4">
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

in form_submit how do I get the $new->id so that I can update (price, name, field, and other) in my table where $new->id is equal to the id in my database.

```
form_submit.php
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $val) {
    $price = $val['price'];
    $name= $val['name'];
    $field= $val['field'];
    $other= $val['other'];

    //stuck here at form_submit
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just replace the `$i` with the `$new->id`?

Comment: note: you should not use the same attribute `id` for your html input fields, it would be best to use a `class` for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your form and use `id` instead of `$i`:

```
<?php 
foreach($row as $new){?>
    <input name='data[<?php $new->id; ?>][price]' id='price' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php $new->id; ?>][name]' id='name' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php $new->id; ?>][field]' id='field' type="number" size="4">
    <input name='data[<?php $new->id; ?>][other]' id='other' type="number" size="4">
<?php
}
```

After that you can iterate:

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $id => $val) {
    $price = $val['price'];
    $name= $val['name'];
    $field= $val['field'];
    $other= $val['other'];

    // update query  will look like:
    UPDATE table SET field = $price, .... WHERE id = $id
}
```